# showing filtered attributes by type

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, filtering

So I have a page that is displaying information about stores.  I have it showing which stores have the status of active and inactive.  I was wondering if there was a way to have it default to showing the active stores first and inactive last, or just showing active only.

This is the section of code I believe is where I need to do this work.  It is the IsActive line I am trying to work with. I am completely unsure how to do this.

```
    <table id="SAPIPartnerList" class="display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Partner Name</td>
                <td>Partner ID</td>
                <td>Is Active</td>
                <td>Account Manager</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          @foreach (var i in Model.SAPIPartners)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.ActionLink(i.Description, "SAPI", "Partner", new { siteNo = i.SiteNo }, null)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => i.PartnerID)</td>
                    <td>@(i.IsActive ? "Active" : "Inactive")</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => i.PartnerAccountManager)</td>

                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.Query))
{ 
    <div class="no-results-row">No Results found</div>
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `SAPIPartners` implements `IEnumerable` in some fashion, you could use LINQ to order by `bool` values:

```
@foreach (var i in Model.SAPIPartners.OrderByDescending(p => p.IsActive))
```

`false` is less than `true`, so that's why we order descending.

After that, you can order by something else if it helps:

```
Model.SAPIPartners.OrderByDescending(p => p.IsActive).ThenBy(p => p.Description)
```

Comment: The simplest solutions are the ones I overlook.  Thank you for that.